# How to write a expression in field calculator for finding $X and $Y?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, coordinates

I'm trying to calculate the lat/long of points using the Q GIS field calculator.Nathan W suggested to First, save the layer as WGS84 and import it again. Then in the field calculator you can use $x or $y as a variable to get the x and y. but the problem is this: i dont know how to write a expression in field calculator for finding $X and $Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your answer already. In field calculator expression, just type '$x' (without the quotes) to populate a Longitude field, and the '$y' for Latitude Field. You calculate them one at a time.

If you don't have a latitude and longitude fields yet, you can select the "Create a new field" box on the top of the dialog and create them.

If you have more doubts about how to use the calculator itself, then the [QGIS user manual](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/user_manual/index.html) is very helpful, take a look into the [field calculator chapter](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html).

Hope it helps!