# How to calculate X and Y coordinate of a surfacic layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, coordinates

I have a surfacic layer in QGIS 2.12.3. I need to calculate the X and Y coordinates for the centroid of my polygons. I created a new field in my attribute table. When I try to use the field calculator, it does not work. In order to solve the problem, I created a new layer with the centroïds of my polygons. In this layer I was able to dertermine the X and Y coordinates. Now, I want to transfer this information to my orignial surfacic layer.

Is it possible to calculate the X and Y coordinates directly from a surfacic layer? If it is possible, how could I do it ? If it is not possible, how can I transfer the X and Y coordinates from my centroïd layer to my surfacic layer attribute table?

I used this post to calculate the X and Y coordinates for my centroïds: [How to write a expression in field calculator for finding $X and $Y?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/how-to-write-a-expression-in-field-calculator-for-finding-x-and-y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't need to create a layer with the centroids of your polygons. In the field calculator of your original layer, just write `xmin(centroid($geometry))` and `ymin(centroid($geometry))` (`xmin()` vs `xmax()` and `ymin()` vs `ymax()` doesn't matter since `centroid()` returns a point).

Comment: I tried the way you suggested and it worked. Thank you. However, i still do not understant the logic beneath the request « xmin(centroid($geometry)) ». Could you explain it please ?

Comment: Well, `$geometry` represents the geometry of your polygon (i.e. the position of its vertices). `centroid` computes the centroid of the geometry, and returns a `geometry` object - a point, this time. `xmin` and `ymin` returns the min x and y coordinates of the centroid geometry, which in this case are exactly the x and y coordinates of the centroid. The only trick is to understand when a geometry object is required (or returned) by a function.

Answer (score 0):

If this two layers has the same ID you can try join attributes by Layer>Propertis>Join

Comment: I tried this option before. I was not able to suceed.